# extract value from line read from text file

Tags: python, string, regular-language

I want to extract the value of the bandwidth from line read from file using this code

```
  try:
        s1 = open(argv[1], "r")
  except IOError:
        print("server1: fopen");
        sys.exit(-1); 

 lines1 = s1.readlines()
 line1 = lines1[c]
 print line1
 f1 = re.split('.Bytes.*', line1)
 print f1
```

the line contains this expression

```
[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec   218 KBytes  1.79 Mbits/sec
```

and

```
print f1
```

gives this value

```
['[  4]  0.0- 1.0 sec   218 ', '\n']
```

I want to read the last number with M letter then compute the number as

```
if M
  B = 1.79*1000000
else if K
  B = 1.79*1000
```

and B must be floating point number

How can I extract the last value?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code and what is not working?

Comment: Your regex pattern is not valid. Try this pattern: .Bytes.*. This will match any single character before Bytes, and any number (including zero) of characters after Bytes.

This probably won't fix your problem completely though. If you want more help, post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this aswell without regex.

```
splitted = filter(None, line1.split())
speed = float(splitted[-2])
unit = splitted[-1]
if "M" in unit:
    B = speed*1000000
else if "K" in unit
    B = speed*1000
```

Let me know how it works -- I haven't tested it yet.